# Trying to get an array of data to send in one email not multiple

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an issue where when I submit the record with 4 orders it sends 4 emails I need assistance in getting the items to all go in one email not an email for each individual item. I will keep trying to figure it out and help would be appreciated. I also know the code needs to be written in a prepared statement I will be changing it after I figure this out.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(~0);

    $serverName = "localhost";
    $userName = "root";
    $userPassword = "";
    $dbName = "blog_samples";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($serverName,$userName,$userPassword,$dbName);

    $rows_count = count($_POST["name"]);

    for($i=0;$i<$rows_count;$i++){

        // PREVENTING SQL INJECTION !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        $employee_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["employee_name"][$i]);
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["name"][$i]);
        $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["code"][$i]);
        $quantity = intval($_POST["quantity"][$i]);
        $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["price"][$i]);


        $sql = "INSERT INTO order_table ( employee_name, name, code, quantity, price) 
            VALUES ('$employee_name', '$name', '$code', '$quantity', '$price')";

        $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0) {
                echo "Record add successfully";



                $to = "xgrh@gmail.com";

                $subject = "Supplies";
                $headers = "From: user@gmail.com";  

                $message =

                "employee_name: " . $employee_name . " 

                " ."name: ".  $name ." 

                ". "code: " . $code . " 

                " ."quantity: ".  $quantity . " 

                ". "price: " . $price . "";


                mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 
            }

        }


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the `mail` command outside of your loop. Instead, compile all the messages into one string then send the message at the end.

For example, something like this:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);

$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "root";
$userPassword = "";
$dbName = "blog_samples";

$conn = mysqli_connect($serverName,$userName,$userPassword,$dbName);

$rows_count = count($_POST["name"]);

$message = '';

for($i=0;$i<$rows_count;$i++){

    // PREVENTING SQL INJECTION !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    $employee_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["employee_name"][$i]);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["name"][$i]);
    $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["code"][$i]);
    $quantity = intval($_POST["quantity"][$i]);
    $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["price"][$i]);


    $sql = "INSERT INTO order_table ( employee_name, name, code, quantity, price) 
        VALUES ('$employee_name', '$name', '$code', '$quantity', '$price')";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0) {
            echo "Record add successfully";

            $message .=

            "employee_name: " . $employee_name . " 

            " ."name: ".  $name ." 

            ". "code: " . $code . " 

            " ."quantity: ".  $quantity . " 

            ". "price: " . $price . "";
    }

}

if ( ! empty($message)) {
    $to = "xgrh@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Supplies";
    $headers = "From: user@gmail.com"; 

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 
}
```

Comment: thank you this worked didn't think to move it out of the for loop